# Fantasy books about a mage in training. His abusive father is a black-clad powerful mage who protects his brother's (the king's) kingdom

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I am looking for a multi-book story I read around 4-6 years ago. Each book was rather short, fitting into the way self published books were released on Amazon. It might have been on Kindle Unlimited. It might have been released for longer.

The story starts with a kingdom putting down an uprising from a small tribe or something similar. The tribe is portrayed somewhat sympathetically, I think.

One of the army leaders or trackers gets an invisibility ring from the kingdom's black-clad archmage/military commander/brother of the king/magic protector of the otherwise small kingdom. (He is all of those things…) Anyway, this mage is later one of the main characters.

The tribe gets ambushed in some caves in the woods, I think. The guy with the invisibility ring uses it to rape one of the warriors and kidnaps her while the tribe is killed.

Later, the rapist brings the woman to the mage, maybe because he wanted him to enchant her to be obedient? The black mage basically rapes the woman too, maybe as payment? I don’t remember the details, the mage put up some thin veneer of "the woman wants to sleep with me, and I am going to ignore everything that screams otherwise." He is in general portrayed as a pretty callous man without many morals.

From that act, our main character is born. He lives with the woman in the woods, and somehow finds his way back to his father. The father trains him as a mage, putting him in the military and in general is very harsh towards him.

The rest of the story I do not remember in this much detail. At some point, our main character learns/discovers teleportation and he meets an atypical dragon (the dragon doesn't want to do typical dragon things and is somewhat nice, maybe he liked to read books?). The black mage/father later gets imprisoned for a time by the other powerful mages, maybe because they want to attack his kingdom?

Comment: Do you remember why the dragon was atypical?

Comment: Edited it in. I think he read books, and after getting to know him he was nice. But it wasn't a major part of the series, more like important for that book.